# WCF Get HTTPS Config

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl

I am trying to configure my WCF service enpoints to be HTTPs and support 2 WCF enpoints (1 regular, 1 RESTFUL (GET)).

I get the following error when I try to browse the SVC.

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

Here are the relevant parts of my web.config

> ```
> <bindings>
>   <mexHttpsBinding>
>     <binding name="mexHttpsBinding1"/>
>  </mexHttpsBinding>
>  <customBinding>
>    <binding name="customBinding0">
>      <binaryMessageEncoding>
>        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
>      </binaryMessageEncoding>
>      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" />
>    </binding>
>    <binding name="customBindingSecure">
>      <binaryMessageEncoding>
>        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
>      </binaryMessageEncoding>
>      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" />
>    </binding>
>  </customBinding>
> ```
>
> ```
> <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
>  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
>    <add prefix="https://myserver1">
>    </add>
>    <add prefix="http://myserver1">
>    </add> 
>  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
> </serviceHostingEnvironment>
>
>
>
> <behaviors>
>  <serviceBehaviors>
>    <behavior name="MyService.Web.Services.Private.WebServiceBehavior">
>      <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" /> 
>      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
>    </behavior>
>    <behavior name="MyService.Web.Services.Public.WebServiceBehavior">
>      <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" /> 
>      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
>    </behavior>
>  </serviceBehaviors>
>  <endpointBehaviors>
>    <behavior name="ImageBehavior">
>      <enableWebScript />
>    </behavior>
>  </endpointBehaviors>
> ```
>
> ```
> <services>
>   <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.Web.Services.Private.WebServiceBehavior"
>     name="MyService.Web.Services.Private.WebService">
>     <endpoint address="https" behaviorConfiguration="ImageBehavior"
>       binding="webHttpBinding" name="PrivateImageBehaviorHTTPs" contract="MyService.Web.Services.Private.WebService" />
>     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexHttpsBinding1" name="PrivateMex"
>       contract="IMetadataExchange" />
>     <endpoint address="https://myserver1/MyService.web.services/private/xifactoryusers.svc"
>       binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBindingSecure"
>       name="PrivateXIFactoryUsersHTTPs" contract="MyService.Web.Services.Private.WebService" />
>   </service>
>   <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.Web.Services.Public.WebServiceBehavior"
>     name="MyService.Web.Services.Public.WebService">
>     <endpoint address="https" behaviorConfiguration="ImageBehavior"
>       binding="webHttpBinding" name="PublicImageBehaviorHTTPs" contract="MyService.Web.Services.Public.WebService" />
>     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding"  bindingConfiguration="mexHttpsBinding1" name="PublicMex"
>       contract="IMetadataExchange" />
>     <endpoint address="https://myserver1/MyService.web.services/public/xifactoryusers.svc"
>       binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBindingSecure"
>       name="PublicXIFactoryUsersHTTPs" contract="MyService.Web.Services.Public.WebService" />
>   </service>
> </services>
> ```

IIS Bindings are good (IIS set to SSL with certificate)

Thanks for any help,
Alex